# How to convert HTML page as well as a Table using jsPDF and Autotable

Tags: html, pdf, jspdf

I've found a lot of information online regarding either JSPDF or Autotable but none that combine both, all I am looking to achieve is to use the ID of the main DIV to generate a full HTML page PDF although I have a table in that page, and would like the table formatted using the Autotable function as it looks awful just using JSPDF.

I have tried variations such as this but nothing seems to work.

My HTML is under `id="content"` and the table is `id="basic_table"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function generate() {  
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');  
    var htmlstring = '';  
    var tempVarToCheckPageHeight = 0;  
    var pageHeight = 0;  
    pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;  
    specialElementHandlers = {  
        // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector  
        '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {  
            // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"  
            return true  
        }  
    };  
    margins = {  
        top: 150,  
        bottom: 60,  
        left: 40,  
        right: 40,  
        width: 600  
    };  
    var y = 20;  
    doc.setLineWidth(2);  
    doc.fromHTML("#content");  
    doc.autoTable({  
        html: '#simple_table',  
        startY: 70,  
        theme: 'grid',  
        columnStyles: {  
            0: {  
                cellWidth: 180,  
            },  
            1: {  
                cellWidth: 180,  
            },  
            2: {  
                cellWidth: 180,  
            }  
        },  
        styles: {  
            minCellHeight: 40  
        }  
    })  
    doc.save('Marks_Of_Students.pdf');  
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Any update on this?